# C# Null Conditional Operator inside method argument

Tags: c#, short-circuiting, null-conditional-operator

I have following methods:

```
float myMethod(MyObject[][] myList) 
{
      float a = 0;
      if (myListProcessingMethod(myList?.Where(x => x.mySatisfiedCondition()).ToList()))
      {
            a = 5;
      }
      return a;
}

bool myListProcessingMethod(List<MyObject[]> myList)
{
      bool isSuccess = false;
      if (myList.Any())
      {
            isSuccess = true;
      }
      return isSuccess;
}
```

I consider this condition:

```
if (myListProcessingMethod(myList?.Where(x => x.mySatisfiedCondition()).ToList()))
```

I refactor my condition to:

```
if (myList?.Length != 0)
{
      if (myListProcessingMethod(myList.Where(x => x.mySatisfiedCondition()).ToList()))
      {
            a = 5;
      }
}
```

Is this two conditions are equivalent? What is equivalent condition to first NullConditionOperator in traditional way? What is equivalent condition to second traditional checking using NullConditionalOperator?

Comment: `List<T>` doesn't have a `Length` property. Did you mean `Count`? Could you provide a [mcve] and test the code for yourself first? Note that if `myList` is null, `myList?.Count` is null, which isn't equal to 0 - so you'd then end up with an exception.

Comment: myListProcessingMethod() can be boiled down to `return myList.Any();` essentially.

Comment: I edit my question: Actually I have an 2 dimensional array of Object in first method arrgument

Comment: Why don't you just say `if (myList?.Any(x => x.satisfiesCondition()) ?? false) { a = 5; }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement below can crash. If `myList` is null, `myList?.Length` will be null and `myList?.Length != 0` will be **true**. That means `myList.Where` may crash with a null reference exception.

```
if (myList?.Length != 0)
{
  if (myListProcessingMethod(myList.Where(x => x.mySatisfiedCondition()).ToList()))
  {
        a = 5;
  }
}
```

you probably want

```
if (myList?.Length > 0) 
...
```

which will evaluate to **true** only if the list is not null and its Length is grater than 0.

Comment: maybe he doesn't use the `System.Collection.Generic.List`. You're missing the point @Badiparmagi

Comment: @Andrew is it possible to join this two if statement as myListProcessingMethod argument?

Comment: @ElConrado you can use `&&` instead of 2 ifs... or what do you mean? You can also make myListProcessingMethod an extension method so you can chain it at the end, after `ToList`.